# How to export full data from excel as a csv using macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, csv, export

I want to export an excel file as a csv using macro, but my code is only exporting the header only. How to export the full data?

Here's my code:

```
 Sub CSVFile()

 Dim My_filenumber As Integer
 Dim logSTR As String

 My_filenumber = FreeFile

 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "A").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "B").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "C").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "D").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "E").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "F").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "G").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "H").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "I").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "J").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "K").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "L").Value & " , "
 logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "M").Value

 Open "C:\Users\folder\Sample.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
  Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
 Close #My_filenumber

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro:

```
Sub Export()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFileName As String

MyFileName = "MR_Update_" & Sheets("Monthly Review").Range("D3").Value & "_" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")

If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"

Sheets("Export Data").Copy

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "" '<~~ The start folder path for the file picker.
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:

With ActiveWorkbook
    .SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV,CreateBackup:=False
    .Close False
End With
End Sub
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568837/excel-macro-export-sheet-to-csv-and-browse-for-save-directory)